# Is there 'stoi()' like thing in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, I'm looking for a stoi()-like function in Java which is in C++.

I want like this:
If there is string like "123ABC", I want extract '123' in Integer and get the index of 'A'.

I've been looking for this, but I couldn't find it. So I upload it here.
In advance, really thank you so much who help me!

Comment: oh... That's what I know, but as you said I must not remove the non-digits. Because I'm making Stack Calculator by inputting expression in String. If you have any idea, tell me please unless you mind.

Answer (score 4):

Use [NumberFormat#parse(String, ParsePosition)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)). The first argument would be "123ABC", the return value will be 123 and the ParsePosition points to A.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try following code:**

```
public class Number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "A1234BCD"; 
        extractDigit(str);
    }

    public static void extractDigit(String str){
           str="A1234AB2C";
           String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
           System.out.println(numberOnly);
           Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}");
           Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
           if (matcher.find()) {
               System.out.println(matcher.start());
           }
    }
```